# Github actions Error: Input required and not supplied: image

Tags: github-actions, amazon-ecs

I used this workflow:

```yaml
name: Deploy to Amazon ECS

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'
env:
  AWS_REGION: ap-southeast-1                   
  ECR_REPOSITORY: web  
  ECS_SERVICE: social-media-app              
  ECS_CLUSTER: dev-cluster            
  ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: .aws/task-definition.json
  CONTAINER_NAME: social-media-app
  
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash

jobs:
  build:
    name: build image and push 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
      contents: read
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set Tag Number
        id: tag-number
        run: echo ::set-output name=tag::${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}

      - name: Check Tag Release
        env:
          RELEASE_VERSION: ${{ steps.tag-number.outputs.tag }}
        run: |
          echo $RELEASE_VERSION
          echo ${{ steps.vars.outputs.tag }}

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
        id: build-image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ steps.tag-number.outputs.tag }}
        run: |
          docker build --file ./Dockerfile -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
          echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"



  deploy-backend:
      name: deploy image
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      needs: build  # Specify that the 'deploy' job depends on the 'build' job
      steps:
        - name: Checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
  
        - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
          id: task-def
          uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
          with:
            task-definition: ${{ env.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
            container-name: ${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}
            image: ${{ needs.build.outputs.image }}
  
        - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
          uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
          with:
            task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
            service: ${{ env.ECS_SERVICE }}
            cluster: ${{ env.ECS_CLUSTER }}
            wait-for-service-stability: false


echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

I tried this:

```yaml
outputs:
      # Define the output variable 'image' for use in other jobs
      image: ${{ steps.image-out.outputs.image }}
```

Comment: You don't set a job output for the `build` job.

Comment: This is also riddled with outdated patterns and versions; have a look at [actionlint](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/) to help you improve that.

Comment: Lastly, I recommend you look into [Open ID Connect](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/configuring-openid-connect-in-amazon-web-services) instead of using secrets for the AWS credentials.